# Почему не работает свойство border-radius top,right,left.bottom в FireFox у таблицы?

Tags: css3, html5, border

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь сделать скругленные края у таблицы, но в FireFox почему-то не работают свойства border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius, border-bottom-left-radius, border-bottom-right-radius
Вот HTML

```
<table class="main-table table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>HTML\CSS</td>
              <td>Bootstrap 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>SASS</td>
              <td>Git</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
              <td>JavaScript\JQuery</td>
              <td>Gulp</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

А вот SASS

```
&-table
  width: 40rem
  margin: 0 auto
  color: #ffffff
  tr:first-child td:first-child
    border-top-left-radius: 15px
  tr:first-child td:last-child
    border-top-right-radius: 15px
  tr:last-child td:first-child
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px
  tr:last-child td:last-child
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px
  tr:nth-child(1)
    background: #FF671A
  tr:nth-child(2)
    background: #150226
  tr:nth-child(3)
    background: #287311
&-table td
  border: 0
  padding-top: 1.5rem
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem
```

При этом в Chrome работает прелестно.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у вас закешировались стили, перезагрузите страницу сочетанием клавиш `Shift + Ctrl + R`.
На какой версии firefox работаете? 
Если последняя версия мозилы то она полностью поддерживает свойства `border-bottom-*`
В этом можно убедится https://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: кеш 1Гб был. Почистил, перезапустил браузер, но не помогло. А не может быть проблемой, что я пишу на angular 2+?

Comment: Скиньте полный код sass файла, думаю у вас где то ошибка в коде, потому что у меня все работает на последней версии мозилы. И ещё вопрос: это весь код который касается таблицы?  https://codepen.io/swartex/pen/ExxKmdZ

Comment: Спасибо большое, натолкнули на мысль и получилось! https://codepen.io/ShurpoSanchezz/pen/yLLOdXa Не так псевдоклассы правильно написал, а вот с бэкграундом накосячил